Unable to add ng-bootstrap 16 to Angular 17 version
It shows the below error :
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@17.3.6
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core 
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"17.3.6" from @angular/animations@17.3.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!     peerOptional @angular/animations@"17.3.6" from @angular/platform-browser@17.3.6
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/platform-browser
npm ERR!       peer @angular/platform-browser@"17.3.6" from @angular/forms@17.3.6
npm ERR!       node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!         @angular/forms@"^17.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR!       3 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router, the root project)
npm ERR!     @angular/animations@"^17.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"17.3.6" from @angular/common@17.3.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!     peer @angular/common@"17.3.6" from @angular/forms@17.3.6
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!       @angular/forms@"^17.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/common@"17.3.6" from @angular/platform-browser@17.3.6
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/platform-browser
npm ERR!       peer @angular/platform-browser@"17.3.6" from @angular/forms@17.3.6
npm ERR!       node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!         @angular/forms@"^17.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR!       3 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router, the root project)
npm ERR!     3 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router, the root project)
npm ERR!   6 more (@angular/compiler, @angular/forms, ...)
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:

npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/core@17.3.7
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"17.3.7" from @angular/forms@17.3.7
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!     @angular/forms@"^17.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/forms@"^17.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@16.0.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!       @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"16.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

I tried this:
npm i @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap --legacy-peer-deps 

ng-bootstrap was installed. But was not able to do an import inside the styles.scss and bootstrap styles were not reflecting in my localhost app.

Modify your package.json by updating all angular packages to ~17.3.6

I modified my entire package.json file for Angular ~17.3.6 and also ~17.3.7
Both the times no luck in adding ng-bootstrap current version ie version 16.

This issue is resolved now.  Popper.js was not getting installed properly and because of that reason many of the dynamics of ng-bootstrap were not working.  Today I uninstalled and added ng-bootstrap once again to give a final try.  This time it got successfully added and everything related to ng-bootstrap is working properly in my project now.  Thanks for all your help for those who have responded to my question.


Make sure you are uisng Angular 17.x.x Version.
If pakage.json has older version of Angular other than specified  then upgrade it to relavant versions as shown in above compatibility table and delete node_modules and do npm install again.

Please don't use images of text. Please don't use images of other websites without citing the website you took it from (see How to reference material written by others)

@heteticmonkey  => verify the original image and this one it is  created by me, no copy rights - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

I modified my entire package.json file for Angular ~17.3.6 and also ~17.3.7
Both the times no luck in adding ng-bootstrap current version ie version 16.
